# Is it idiomatic to say a [name of month]?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Example:

> The girl disappeared a September, the Ghost Month.

I want to express that this is a September in the past and not in the current year. Is this the correct way? If not, what's a better alternative?

(Or maybe saying "in September" doesn't imply that it's a September in the current year or in the present?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Native speakers seldom if ever use the indefinite article unaccompanied when referring to a single named month.

Here are some more felicitous native usages:

> The girl disappeared on a September ... [with a follow-up like *day* or *morning*]
>
> The girl disappeared one September ...
>
> The girl disappeared during September ...
>
> The girl disappeared in September ...

None of these will be what you're looking for, I'm afraid. But you'd be better off using one of them than "The girl disappeared a September," which will only identify you right away as a non-native speaker.

The first two examples would be used to refer to a September in years past; the latter two would refer to the previous (or current) September *unless* another year was specified.

Comment: Did you mean your first example to read ***in** a September* or possibly *on a **[day/morning/etc.]** in September* ? The way it is now doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Comment: @1006a "in a September" doesn't sound natural to me. "on a September [day/morning/etc.]" sounds natural. I don't see a problem with suggesting "on a September **...**"

Comment: "On a September morning" sounds fine to me, but simply "on a September" definitely does not. Maybe add a note making this explicit?

Comment: Yep, that's what I had in mind. Edited to make it explicit now.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga *in a* doesn't sound particularly natural to me, either, but I can imagine making it sort-of work for the OP's purposes: *The girl disappeared **in a September (the Ghost Month) several years ago***. A little awkward, but understandable. I didn't suggest the current formulation, which I agree sounds most natural, because it doesn't work with the desired aside. The specified time needs to come earlier: *The girl disappeared **on a morning in** September, the Ghost Month.* But possibly *The girl disappeared **in "the Ghost Month", on a September morning*** would work.